# What is the Phone Number format for incoming calls in India

Tags: android, phone-number

I have an Android application that shows the location based on the area code of a caller.  For example, any phone number with the area code 212 is New York.  I would like to let users in India use the application.

With some research it looks like one of the phone number format for India is:

(0)5555 + 6 digits

For Android users in India, what do numbers look like when you get an incoming call?

Answer (score 2):

In India, we get the full number. Like +1-212-xxx-xxxx will be from someone in US maybe. The +1 in the beginning is something called a country code. For India it is +91.

The (0)5555-.. does not look like a valid number but it is probably something you will see when your call gets routed over VOIP and the caller id gets lost somewhere. The number is a combination of country code, area code and the number.

So +91-11-xxxx-xxxx will be the number of someone in Delhi area in India. 
It is more difficult to pinpoint for mobile numbers as there is no city/area code there. A number like +91-9482828282 could be anywhere in the country and you will have to ask the operator where it is from

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes sense.  So if I am in India I will get the country code in the number.  In the US, the country code (1) sometimes comes with the number. If I am understanding correctly if the number is from (for example) Pathankot  the number would look like +91-186-XXX-XXXX, But if the call is from Kotputli that number would look like +91-1421-XX-XXXX. There will be 10 digits for the entire number, but the first block after the country code would be the area code.